# matplotlib drops IndexError: tuple index out of range after upgrade

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I made a mistake upgrading Python libraries and now matplotlib drops an error of:

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

on a very simple code which worked yesterday.

Consider [this big CSV file](https://surfdrive.surf.nl/files/index.php/s/jc9n7LpN3pWhIC2), which I plotted yesterday by:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

headers = ['fx', 'fy', 'fz', 'tx', 'ty', 'tz', 'currentr',
           'time', 'theta', 'omegay', 'currenty', 'pr', 'Dc', 'Fr', 'Fl']
df = pd.read_csv('20190802_pase3part1_test3PC-c156.csv', names=headers)

fig3 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(df.index, df['time'])
plt.show()
```

but after the upgrade I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-1ce3610bc7d8> in <module>
      1 fig3 = plt.figure()
----> 2 plt.plot(df.index, df['time'])
      3 plt.show()

c:\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2793     return gca().plot(
   2794         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley, **({"data": data} if data
-> 2795         is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2796 
   2797 

c:\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1664         """
   1665         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D._alias_map)
-> 1666         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1667         for line in lines:
   1668             self.add_line(line)

c:\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    223                 this += args[0],
    224                 args = args[1:]
--> 225             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    226 
    227     def get_next_color(self):

c:\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    397             func = self._makefill
    398 
--> 399         ncx, ncy = x.shape[1], y.shape[1]
    400         if ncx > 1 and ncy > 1 and ncx != ncy:
    401             cbook.warn_deprecated(

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I presume it is a bug but I don't know what is causing it.

my environment is:

- matplotlib: 3.1.1
- Python: 3.7.4
- OS: Windows 1809 (OS Build 17763.615)

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the issue and how I can resolve it?

**P.S.1.** I just tried the code on another computer with matplotlib `3.0.3` and it just worked!

**P.S.2.** issues a bug [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14992)

**P.S.3.** I just tried downgrading to the previous versions by:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib==<version>
```

but it did not work!

**P.S.4.** Ok it turns out to be a pandas bug. Downgrading from `0.25` to `0.24` solved the problem! ([details](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14992#issuecomment-518615405))

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Version 3.1.0 makes the plot, version 3.1.1 gives the error.  You should raise an issue on their github page.

Comment: @James I just did ([here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14992)) but in the meantime, I'm curious to know what is the bug. Maybe I can learn and send pull requests next time.

Comment: Start looking at the `_base.py` file on the github repo.  It is located [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py).  There is nothing particularly odd in the last line of code from the error message.  A few lines up, `x` and `y` are declared in several if-blocks.  The code in 3.1.0 uses `x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)`.  Browsing the repo, you can see it was removed by commit 4da5bc1ef7f32607e6028a3d66b5e1eca0910977.

Comment: @James so you are telling me that this line was required and someone just removed it? and the main devs did not check for diffs?  that, if true, is unsettling!

Comment: @James are you sure it is a matplotlib bug? I just downgraded to `3.0.3` and `3.1.0` none worked!

Comment: @James Pandas `0.25` was the problem. Downgrading to `0.24` solved the error!

Comment: I can confirm that I had the same bug and the problem was resolved by going back to pandas 0.24.2.